# Should I define number of elements in a vector before or after knowing how many elements I'll use?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to understand which way I should implement a vector so I can reduce my run time and memory usage in a program or it doesn't matter (depending solely of the computations my program does with those elements)?

Let's say I define a vector without knowing how many elements I'll use in my program but I know the max number of elements I'll be working with

```
#define MAX 10000
vector<int> eg(MAX);
```

In the other case I indicate first how many elements and then size it accordingly

```
vector<int> eg;
int n;
cin >> n;
eg.resize(n);
```

Comment: There is almost no difference among the two in terms of performace. What are you trying to achieve? If you know that your vector may be of size 10000 most of the time, then use the first declaration. If it "may happen" that your vector could be of size 10000 (but with low probability), then don't worry about resizing it. It is all a matter of how probable the vector's size is to reach a given value.

Comment: The suggestion is to reduce the number of resizes that the `std::vector` performs.  If you know you have a size of 1000, reserve that many.  You should profile and find the average number of items and reserve a little more.  Your decision is on how many resizes your program can perform for those times when your vector needs to be expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of elements that the vector will store then it is better to use member function `reserve`. For example

```
const std::vector<int>::size_type MAX = 10000;
vector<int> eg;
eg.reserve( MAX );
```

Answer (score 0):

Both. Because when you go to `resize` to the final number of elements, you will only be resizing to a lesser number of elements and that takes fewer cpu cycles than resizing to a greater number of elements (if you hadn't set MAX) because it doesn't have to copy elements to different locations if there isn't room in the current contiguous location.